# How to create index in elasticsearch container from spark container

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, pyspark, bigdata

I can't create new index from my spark container to my elasticsearch container

I run docker-hadoop-spark in Docker Desktop, here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: "3"

services:
  namenode:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-namenode:2.0.0-hadoop3.2.1-java8
    container_name: namenode
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 9870:9870
      - 9000:9000
    volumes:
      - hadoop_namenode:/hadoop/dfs/name
    environment:
      - CLUSTER_NAME=test
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env

  datanode:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-datanode:2.0.0-hadoop3.2.1-java8
    container_name: datanode
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 9864:9864
    volumes:
      - hadoop_datanode:/hadoop/dfs/data
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:9870"
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env
  datanode1:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-datanode:2.0.0-hadoop3.2.1-java8
    container_name: datanode1
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 9865:9864
    volumes:
      - hadoop_datanode1:/hadoop/dfs/data
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:9870"
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env
  
  datanode2:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-datanode:2.0.0-hadoop3.2.1-java8
    container_name: datanode2
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 9866:9864
    volumes:
      - hadoop_datanode2:/hadoop/dfs/data
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:9870"
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env

  resourcemanager:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-resourcemanager:2.0.0-hadoop3.2.1-java8
    container_name: resourcemanager
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8088:8088
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:9000 namenode:9870 datanode:9864 datanode1:9864 datanode2:9864"
    
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env

  nodemanager1:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-nodemanager:2.0.0-hadoop3.2.1-java8
    container_name: nodemanager
    restart: always
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:9000 namenode:9870 datanode:9864 datanode1:9864 datanode2:9864 resourcemanager:8088"
    
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env
  
  historyserver:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-historyserver:2.0.0-hadoop3.2.1-java8
    container_name: historyserver
    restart: always
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:9000 namenode:9870 datanode:9864 datanode1:9864 datanode2:9864 resourcemanager:8088"
     
    volumes:
      - hadoop_historyserver:/hadoop/yarn/timeline
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env

  spark:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/spark:latest
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=master
      - SPARK_RPC_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_RPC_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_LOCAL_STORAGE_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_SSL_ENABLED=no
      - CORE_CONF_fs_defaultFS=hdfs://namenode:9000
      - SPARK_USER=root
      - PYTHONPATH= '/opt/bitnami/spark/python/:/opt/bitnami/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip:/opt/bitnami/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip:/opt/bitnami/spark/python/:'

    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
      - '7077:7077'

    container_name: spark

    volumes:
      - spark:/spark


  
  spark-worker-1:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/spark:latest
    container_name: spark-worker-1
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=worker
      - SPARK_MASTER_URL=spark://spark:7077
      - SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=1G
      - SPARK_WORKER_CORES=1
      - SPARK_RPC_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_RPC_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_LOCAL_STORAGE_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_SSL_ENABLED=no
      - CORE_CONF_fs_defaultFS=hdfs://namenode:9000
    ports:
      - '8081:8081'
    depends_on:
      - spark
  spark-worker-2:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/spark:latest
    container_name: spark-worker-2
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=worker
      - SPARK_MASTER_URL=spark://spark:7077
      - SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=1G
      - SPARK_WORKER_CORES=1
      - SPARK_RPC_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_RPC_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_LOCAL_STORAGE_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_SSL_ENABLED=no
      - CORE_CONF_fs_defaultFS=hdfs://namenode:9000
    ports:
      - '8082:8081'
    depends_on:
      - spark
  spark-worker-3:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/spark:latest
    container_name: spark-worker-3
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=worker
      - SPARK_MASTER_URL=spark://spark:7077
      - SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=1G
      - SPARK_WORKER_CORES=1
      - SPARK_RPC_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_RPC_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_LOCAL_STORAGE_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_SSL_ENABLED=no
      - CORE_CONF_fs_defaultFS=hdfs://namenode:9000
    ports:
      - '8083:8081'
    depends_on:
      - spark

  elasticsearch:
    container_name: elasticsearch 
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.10.0
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    volumes:
      - elasticsearch-data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data

  kibana:
    container_name: kibana
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.10.0
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch


  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    container_name: zookeeper
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    ports:
      - 22181:2181

  
  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.1.1
    container_name: kafka
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - '9092:9092'
    expose:
      - '29092'
    environment:
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: '1'
      KAFKA_MIN_INSYNC_REPLICAS: '1'

  
volumes:
  hadoop_namenode:
  hadoop_datanode:
  hadoop_datanode1:
  hadoop_datanode2:
  hadoop_historyserver:
  spark:
  spark-lab:
  elasticsearch-data:
```

I have been run this Pyspark code in spark container:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.streaming._
import org.elasticsearch.spark.sql._
# Initialize Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("ElasticsearchIntegration") \
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-spark-30_2.12:7.10.0") \
    .getOrCreate()

# Sample JSON DataFrame
data = [("John", 28), ("Jane", 22), ("Doe", 25)]
columns = ["Name", "Age"]
json_df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)

# Elasticsearch configuration
es_config = {
    "es.nodes": "http://localhost",  # replace with your Elasticsearch container hostname or IP
    "es.port": "9200",  # replace with your Elasticsearch container port
    "es.resource": "index_name/type",  # replace with your desired index and type
    "es.write.operation": "index",
    "es.mapping.id": "Name"  # replace with a unique identifier for each document
}

# Write DataFrame to Elasticsearch
json_df.write.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql") \
    .options(**es_config) \
    .mode("append") \
    .save()

# Stop the Spark session
spark.stop()
```

But I have two error: Failed to find the datasource: org.elastisearch.spark.sql
Then I change the format to "json" and it responses the new error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/bitnami/spark/pyspark/elasticsearch_create_index.py", line 28, in <module>
    .save()
     ^^^^^^
  File "/opt/bitnami/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 1461, in save
  File "/opt/bitnami/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1322, in __call__
  File "/opt/bitnami/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/errors/exceptions/captured.py", line 185, in deco
pyspark.errors.exceptions.captured.IllegalArgumentException: Expected exactly one path to be specified, but got:
```

.

I try to make a Put request with my `dataframe` to http:localhost:9200 but it didn't work.

Please help me! Thank you so much.